# What dimensions should images be in rich push notifications?

Tags: marketing-cloud, images, mobilepush

I have searched in the [documentation](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/features/picture-notifications.html), but could not see anywhere the recommended size for the rich push notifications.

Does anyone know the preferred size or ratio (16:9, 2:1, ...)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no preferred size but a StackOverflow search would indicate the [community has settled on a 2:1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189876/big-picture-is-cropping-while-setting-to-notification/33391039#33391039).  The Android OS is handling how your image will be displayed and there are no other SDK dependencies.

Comment: I tried with both 2:1 and 16:9 in just one mobile and 2:1 is cropped while the 16:9 is not. I'll keep trying with more devices and post here the results.

Comment: it looks like the better aspect ratio for all devices is 16:9

Answer (score 0):

Recommend minimum, balanced, and maximum sizes below:

- Minimum : 512x256
- Balanced : 1024x512
- Maximum : 2048x1024

Comment: Source for these dimensions?